# How to make `wp-list-table` show the` custom-fields` I have in Custom-Post

Tags: php, wp-list-table

everything good?
I need the `wp-list-table` to also show `custom-fields` in each `custom-post` i have, and I do not know how to do that,
In this image it shows the table with the fields: **Title, Author and Publication Date**:

[image]

What I want is to be able to choose which `custom-fields` will appear, such as the following example, being **Title, Carta, Naipe, Author, and Date of Publication**:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved Situation:

```
 // Add the custom columns to the copas post type:
    add_filter( 'manage_copas_posts_columns', 'set_custom_edit_copas_columns' );
    function set_custom_edit_copas_columns($columns) {
        //unset( $columns['author'] );
      $columns['coluna_carta'] = __( 'Carta', 'your_text_domain' );
      $columns['coluna_naipe'] = __( 'Naipe', 'your_text_domain' );
      $columns['coluna_situacao'] = __( 'Situacao', 'your_text_domain' );
      return $columns;
    }

    add_action( 'manage_copas_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_copas_column', 10, 2 );
    function custom_copas_column( $column, $post_id ) {
      switch ( $column ) {
        case 'coluna_carta' :
        echo get_post_meta( $post_id , 'dbt_carta' , true ); 
        break;

        case 'coluna_naipe' :
        echo get_post_meta( $post_id , 'dbt_naipe' , true ); 
        break;

        case 'coluna_situacao' :
        echo get_post_meta( $post_id , 'dbt_situacao' , true ); 
        break;

      }
    }
```